# Elegant way to check multiple if conditions in Dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a dataframe dictionary like as shown below

```
dataFramesDict[sheet_name] = pd.DataFrame({'Date':['2007-05-30','2107-11-30','2207-05-20','2307-05-20'],'Value': [2.4,2.5,2.6,2.7],'Test': ['Height','Weight','SBP','DBP']})
```

[image]

What I would like to do is create a new column called `Unit` and add values based on `Test` column

This is what I tried but this doesn't look elegant or efficient.

```
if dataFramesDict[sheet_name]['Test'] == 'Height':
    dataFramesDict[sheet_name]['unit'] == 'm'
if dataFramesDict[sheet_name]['Test'] == 'Weight':
    dataFramesDict[sheet_name]['unit'] == 'kg'
if dataFramesDict[sheet_name]['Test'] == 'SBP':
    dataFramesDict[sheet_name]['unit'] == 'millimeter'
if dataFramesDict[sheet_name]['Test'] == 'DBP':
    dataFramesDict[sheet_name]['unit'] == 'millimeter'
```

Please note that `sheet_name` is part of an excel sheet. In total I have more than 10 sheets for which I would like to read each sheet and check the test value in each sheet and assign the unit value based on `Test` column

I expect my output to be like as shown below

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `map` with `dict`

**Ex:**

```
d = {'Height':"m",'Weight': "kg",'SBP':'mm','DBP':'mm'}
dataFramesDict = pd.DataFrame({'Date':['2007-05-30','2107-11-30','2207-05-20','2307-05-20'],'Value': [2.4,2.5,2.6,2.7],'Test': ['Height','Weight','SBP','DBP']})
dataFramesDict["Unit"] = dataFramesDict["Test"].map(d)
print(dataFramesDict)
```

**Output:**

```
         Date    Test  Value Unit
0  2007-05-30  Height    2.4    m
1  2107-11-30  Weight    2.5   kg
2  2207-05-20     SBP    2.6   mm
3  2307-05-20     DBP    2.7   mm
```

Comment: Is there anyway to do this with a file? For example, I have a csv file with all the units and corresponding tests. How do we map then?

Comment: @SSMK yes, you need to convert those mapping into a python dictionary object first

Answer (score 2):

Use Pandas replace

```
df['unit'] = df.Test.replace({'Height':"m",'Weight': "kg",'SBP':'mm','DBP':'mm'})
```

Comment: @SSMK why have you deleted the post. I was working on the solution.

Comment: Will share the link of 2nd part soon. You can provide your answer and I will respond to it. Hope that's okay. Thanks for your comment on my old question

Answer (score 1):

Please try the below code. Hope it helps:

```
unitDict = {'Height':'m', 'Weight': 'Kg', 'SBP':'millimeter', 'DBP':'millimeter'}


def checkUnit(data):
  if unitDict[data] is not None:
    return unitDict[data]

df['Unit']=list(map(checkUnit, df['Test']))

print(df)
```

Comment: Can you help me with this post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57667919/how-to-build-custom-operation-as-a-calculator-to-handle-million-rows-efficiently